# The distribution of a normal random variable and a constant

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

We have variable $X_1$, which is a constant number, and $X_2$ ~ $N(X_1, \sigma^2)$, so $X_2$ is dependent on $X_1$.

We are interested in sampling from $ Y = -(X_2 - X_1) $

Since $X_1$ is a constant, all that happens is here is a normal distribution being shifted by a constant, so $Y$ is just a shifted normal distribution? I am having trouble deriving the distribution of $Y$

Comment: "We have variable 1, which is a constant number,"  This makes no sense.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork OP is probably looking for a proof that uses conditional distributions to find the distribution of $Y$

Comment: @DavidG.Stork It does: it's a [degenerate RV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degenerate_distribution). But then of course $X1$ and $X2$ are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
For any event $E$,
$$
P(Y \in E) = P(-(X_2 - X_1) \in E) = P(X_2 \in -E + X_1),
$$
where $E$ is a set and $-E + X_1 = \{-x + X_1 \mid x\in E\}$.  Since $X_2$ is normally distributed, the probability that $Y$ is in $E$ is the same as that given by the normal distribution if $E$ is reflected then shifted up by $X_1$.  If you write out the change of variables on either the pdf or cdf, you will see that $Y \sim N(0, \sigma)$.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for this response, this makes sense